# Database Insert with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to insert some data to database. Using `javascript` But Now it seems like everything is messed up .How can i fix this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//veritabanına ürün ekleme yapacağımız fonksiyon
//onreadystatechange ile durum değişikliği kontrolü yaptık.
function add() {
    var request;
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "Webform1.aspx");
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readystate == 4) {
                request.send("mail=" + document.all.Text1.value);
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend that you use your server-side code to insert into your database.

Comment: Just learning purpose

Comment: why are doing `send` within `readystatechange`?

Comment: You're not doing "Database Insert with Javascript" in this code. You're just executing POST request to your form (and wrongly too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using jQuery to do the POST to the server, because it will eliminate the cross-browser issues you will run into with XHR (XmlHttpRequest), like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "Webform1.aspx",
    data: {'mail': mailValue },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); 
    }
});
```

You can also pass via the query string, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "Webform1.aspx?mail=mailValue",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); 
    }
});
```

Second, I would recommend you call a service on the server, such as: ASP.NET XML Web Service `.asmx`, WCF, ASP.NET Web API, or ASP.NET AJAX Page Method, because it will give you the endpoint you need to for your JavaScript to communicate with the server, but not the entire overhead of a full ASP.NET page.